# How to override PrintWriterServletOutputStream to write bytes instead of encoded string to HTTP response

Tags: java, servlets, portlet, outputstream, printwriter

When calling a servlet through  a portlet, the j`avax.portlet.ResourceResponse.getPortletOutputStream()` method of the portlet resource response returns a `org.apache.pluto.container.util.PrintWriterServletOutputStream` object. 
(I am not sure whether this method does not return `PrintWriterServerOutputStream` always.)

`PrintWriterServletOutputStream` object writes an encoded string to output, instead of raw bytes as expected from a `OutputStream` object.

I want to modify this behavior to write raw bytes to the browser output.

Please let me know how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: What are you trying to avoid?